# How do I make a functional main menu working?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have the game play set to the first frame within Adobe Animate/Flash and I have main menu at frame 2. But how do I make the game start at frame 2 now instead of frame one, but so that I could move back to frame one and play within it, as it is where the gameplay will be happening.

Making a variable, which would control the frames and have it not exist on the first frame could work, but for me it just gives the 1009 error.

Tried to make main menu at frame two, but all it does is make the first frame freeze and not do anything at all in terms of gameplay. Why, I've no idea.

Comment: Stop using multiple frames with different codes for different things. It's done in tutorials for day-1 experience but don't try and make a full app this way. A `MovieClip` object has a timeline (just like Stage) if you really want different "visual elements" in different frames...

Comment: PS: try and add some code especially the segment that causes error, someone might edit it for you.

Comment: So, you're suggesting I have to make everything on one frame? Fantastic... I'll just redo everything then and keep levels layered in folders then.

Comment: "*I'm doing everything right.*" no, you aren't.

Comment: @XirmiX "cut & paste" is not re-doing everything it's actually **moving** things to a different place (so the compiler can find them). What layered folders are you talking about now? Just try the advice in my answer (it has worked better for me since 2009).

Comment: @XirmiX if it seems too much (why be a programmer?) then try dragging (by mouse) the keyframes in the timeline. Drag current frame-1 to be ahead of current frame-2 (swap their positions). It's lazy but it might work...

Comment: stackoverflow really isn't meant to be a rant publishing site.  I've edited your question to focus on the technical aspects rather than "I'm frustrated with AS3"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you create a `MovieClip` called "containerMC" and then use *cut frames* (right click on timeline after selecting frames) to grab your existing frames. Now go inside the container MC's timeline and use *paste frames* option.

Now you have **content** on layer 1 and **code** on layer 2 but everything is on **frame 1 only**. If you want content to go to frame 1 then simply use:

`contentMC.gotoAndStop(1);` etc.

This should avoid 1009 error. Your code always knows that it's talking to `containerMC` (and that timeline) which is always available on the same frame as code (just different layer).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I simply put everything on one frame and it did the trick of everything working and I simulated "menu" and "level" by foldering layers of things under folders and using variables. This game is an assignment, so I can't not program it. And if I want to be an indie developer sooner or later, I'll need to be able to know at least SOME bit about programming.